# android - FragmentActivity instead of TabActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

**My goal is to create an `Activity` with 5 tabs** where the content of each `Tab` is a `ListView` (content varies depending on the tab). Each `Tab` should have an icon. I was intended to do it using a `TabHost` but the SDK told me that it's deprecated. So I decided to try the new API and created a new `Activity` by selecting 'Fixed Tabs + Swipe' as navigation type. Eclipse created tons of code (I'm using pastebin to keep the question more clear): http://pastebin.com/phntzbME,

it also created a `ViewPager` in main Layout and a dummy fragment layout.

I ran it (on SGS2 I9100 @4.1.2) only to test how it'd look like but it crashes with a `NullPointerException`. It seems like `final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` returns null.

I'm not familiar with the new API and I've been working with 2.2 and 2.3 for a long time. *Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and how do I get the desired result?*

**Edit:**

how can I remove the "section1... etc" text and replace it by an icon?

[image]

Comment: did you change your theme of the project to use the action bar `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` for example? If you didnt then that is why `getActionBar` is returning null

Comment: ah thanks. Got it working. But how do I remove the titleBar then? Since I need no title. I tried  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in my onCreate()  but it started to crash again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your theme to use the holo theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`for example.

to get rid of the title next to the icon simply do this

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Comment: thanks. A couple more things.. please view my edited question. The code is on pastebin (link inside the question)